# How can I make the Informix 4GL press a key for me?

Tags: informix, 4gl

I have a situation where the program waits for the user to press accept and then starts to do some actions. If a certain condition is true, I would like to get all the actions. I could type:

`if condition = true then ...`

But the 'then' is too much of codes. It would be much easier if I can write something like:

`if true then press accept`

So it will treat as if the user pressed it. I couldn't find any way so far. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to explain why it would be better to do what you're suggesting than to write:

```
IF condition != TRUE THEN
    …input operation waiting for ACCEPT…
END IF
CALL function_to_do_actions(…)
```

(You don't even have to call a function; you can simply write the actions following the test.)

I don't think there's a documented way of doing what you're asking — faking a key-press.

Comment: I do want to have all operations that are happening now after pressing accept. I just want it to happen without the accept if true. The operations are checking on a lot of requirements before calling the function  I don't want to skip them. And the actions is over 4000 rows of codes that I'm trying to avoid to write again. Well, I ended up doing a goto label (if true then goto skip_accept where the label is after the accept and the program treats it as if you're already pressed it..) and it works just as I wanted. But still interested if there's any way to fake a key-press.

Comment: A GOTO skipping 4000 lines of code is a worrying proposition.

Comment: No. It only skips the accept key and then continues as if you pressed it... If true goto skip_accept end if if pressed accept then label skip_accept: actions..... Functions... End if. Got it?